# Update component UI based on values obtained from SubmitForm Component using redux toolkit state management

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-forms

My store.js file

```
import commentsReducer from "./stateSlices/commentsSlice";
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        dishes: dishesReducer,
        comments: commentsReducer,
        leaders: leadersReducer,
        promotions: promotionsReducer,
    },
});
```

My commentsSlice.js file

```
import { COMMENTS } from "../../shared/comments";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    comments: COMMENTS,
};
export const stateSlice = createSlice({
    name: "comments",
    initialState,
// Updated the reducer file as below
reducers: {
        addComment: {
            reducer: (state = initialState.comments, action) => {
                state.comments = state.comments.concat(action.payload);
            },
            prepare: (value) => {
                return {
                    payload: {
                        ...value,
                        date: new Date().toISOString(),
                        id: Math.random(),
                    },
                };
            },
        },
    },

});

export default stateSlice.reducer;
```

My dishdetail.js file

```
const Dishdetail = (props) => {
    if (props.dish != null) {
        return (
            <div className="container ">
                <div className="row ">
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <RenderComments comments={props.comments} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return <div></div>;
    }
};

export default Dishdetail;
```

RenderComments component implementation

```
function RenderComments({ comments, commentsName }) {
// created dishId constant to get the dishId of selected dish and 
//need only first index dishId and passed it as prop to 
//SubmitComment component as file like this
//changed below line
const dishId = comments.map((x) => x.dishId)[0];
    if (comments != null) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    {comments.map((comment) => {
                        const options = { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "2-digit" };
                        return (
                            <div key={comment.id}>
                                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                    <li>{comment.comment}</li>
                                    <li>
                                        --{comment.author} {new Date(comment.date).toLocaleDateString("en-us", options)}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                    <SubmitComment dishId={dishId} />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    } else {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
```

and My SubmitComment.js component

```
function SubmitComment() {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
    const {
        register,
        formState: { errors },
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
    } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
// to get the data from input fields
const { rating, author, comment } = data;
//dispatched the addComment action, here dishId is from props 
        dispatch(addComment({ dishId, rating, author, comment }));

// Finally subscribed to the store by useSelector method in main
// component which is parent component of renderComments component 
//which in turn is parent component of SubmitComments component

        reset();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
                <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} fade={false}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Submit Comment</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="rating" className="form-label">
                                    Rating
                                </label>
                                <select
                                    name="rating"
                                    className="form-select "
                                    aria-label="Default select example"
                                    {...register("rating")}
                                >
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                                    Your Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="name"
                                    placeholder="Your Name"
                                    name="name"
                                    {...register("name", { required: true, maxLength: "15" })}
                                />
                                <small className="form-text text-danger">
                                    {errors.name?.type === "required" && "This field is required"}
                                    {errors.name?.type === "maxLength" && "Maximum 15 characters are allowed"}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="comment" className="form-label">
                                    Comment
                                </label>
                                <textarea
                                    type="text"
                                    name="comment"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="comment"
                                    aria-describedby="comment"
                                    rows="6"
                                    {...register("comment")}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default SubmitComment;
```

I am expecting that once I click on the submitcomment form, all the values that I entered in the fields namely rating, author and comments should get added in the renderComment component.

[image]

like this
[image]
I have tried to add dispatch action after clicking on submit in form and tried to use it in rendercomments component file using useSelector but i am unable to do it

So if anyone can describe the redux flow and basic working flow from here so I could implement this functionality

Comment: Finallly desired functionality is achieved

Answer (score 0):

1 Created reducer in commentSlice.js file

2 In Dishdetail component made following changes:
In renderComments function
created dishId constant to get the dishId of selected dish and
need only first index dishId and passed it as prop to
SubmitComment component which is child component of renderComments

3 Received dishId as prop in SubmitComment and passed it as payload along with other valued received from the user input fields to the action addComment using dispatch

4 Finally subscribed the new state in Main component using useSelectore and passed as prop to Dishdetail component which is child component of main component

Successfully achieved the desired functionality.

I have updated the question with the changes.